# How to configure the Linux client for registering in Dynamic DNS

Tags: linux, shell, dns

I have a host such as : myhostdomain.example.com and static ip(or from dhcp).

And I have the right dns server configure in my linux host, i can ping out internet website successfully.

Ower DNS zone is a dynamic zone where computers register their DNS name.
this linux computer fails to verify registration over a period of time, the name has be deleted. This is an autoaic process to ensure that stale records are removed.

Is there anyway to register my hostname myhostdomain.example.com into dns server again. Or how to configure the Linux client for registering in Dynamic DNS.

I known For Windows computers, use the command

```
"ipconfig /registerdns" .
```

Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

sample

```
nsupdate
update add xxx.yyy.com. 600 a 10.11.12.13
update delete www.example.com cname
update delete www1.example.com a
update add xxx.yyy.com 600 a 10.11.12.13
update add aaa.yyy.com  600 cname xxx.yyy.com.
send
```

And reference:

https://serverfault.com/questions/783864/windows-dns-server-register-a-non-dhcp-client-server-into-2008r2/783976#783976

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/nsupdate.htm